# fallo en metodo post con django

Tags: python, html5, django

estoy intentando cargar un vídeo y luego reproducirlo en la web, estoy usando `django-python`.

Tengo el settings. y configurado con las rutas de `MEDIA_URL = "/media/"`  que es una carpeta que tengo en la ruta raíz del proyecto. (igual que la de `static`).

Tengo el siguiente código:

Código HTML (`home.html`):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{%block content%}


<h1>Video Uploader</h1>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<br><br>
<video width='400' controls>
<source src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ videofile }}' type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br><br>
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Código `forms.py`:

```
from .models import Video
from django import forms

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model= Video
    fields= ["name", "videofile"]
```

Código `url.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'appJM'
urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^$', views.PagPrincipal.as_view(), name = 'home'),
]
```

Código `views.py`:

```
from .models import Video
from .forms import VideoForm


class PagPrincipal(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'home.html'

def showvideo(request):

    lastvideo= Video.objects.last()

    videofile= lastvideo.videofile


    form= VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
    form.save()


    context= {'videofile': videofile,
              'form': form
              }


    return render(request, 'templates/home.html', context)


Código `models.py`:


    class Video(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
        videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
```

Estos son los códigos que tengo realizados, cuando le doy a `upload` en home me sale:

`Method Not Allowed (POST): /
[14/Jun/2019 12:53:56] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

Y no se en que puede estar fallando.

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: cambia en el view html el action a `action="{% url "home" %}" `

Answer (score 2):

La clase `TemplateView` está diseñada para aceptar sólo el verbo GET, ya que es una clase para renderizar una plantilla, como su propio nombre indica. Si necesitas que la misma ruta acepte tanto `GET` como `POST`, tienes que crear una clase heredando de `View` con los métodos `get` y `post` o hacerlo de otra forma. Mira [la documentación de Django al respecto](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/#supporting-other-http-methods).